# two js file with same name in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know what happens when you have two js file in one page with same name.
I accidentally put two js files with same name on my page and sometimes both would work, other times just one would work and the other wouldn't.
When I load the page, firebug doesn't show any error.

So can anybody tell me exactly what happens in such a case? Not that I want to write a thesis on this but just curious.

Comment: The code in the script is effectively just run twice. Global symbols are redefined, etc.

Comment: No, I mean I had two different set of codes from two diffent folders with the same file name

Comment: The name of the file used has absolutely no effect on how the script runs. No effect whatsoever.

Comment: Sometimes, JS files will have various ways of safeguarding against multiple-inclusion; although it's usually better to just only include it once. For instance: "myGlobalLibrary = myGlobalLibrary || (function() { ...the whole code... })()" EDIT: But as Pointy said, simply having the same filename isn't an issue at all - two files of the same name in different directories can do different things.

Comment: I'm willing to bet in the sometimes non functioning file you forgot to wait for `onLoad`. Regardless, file name is not the issue, please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a browser dependant issue, where probably IE will fail (kill me if I'm wrong).

The thing is, these files with the same name, e.g. js.js have to be in different directories, therefore they will be read as different files, nothing should happen or mess up your JS.

If I include the 2 following files with the same name, both would simply work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dir1/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dir1/subdir1/js.js"></script>
```

The browser simply gets the contents of the file and executes what is in them as soon as it's called by a handler etc.

Name should not matter, however you mentioned that it did not work sometimes.

This is **probably** a common mistake of including the same `src` twice.

Hope this helped you.

‐ Sid